# Linux route add with subdomains wildcard -host *.domain.com

Tags: linux, dns, subdomain, wildcard, routes

if I have a script with the following two commands to modify a route

/sbin/route add -host pandora.com -interface ppp0
/sbin/route add -host internal-tuner.pandora.com -interface ppp0

Is there a way to create a one unique command route with something like *.pandora.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is no. When you add a route using the dns name instead of the ip address, the first thing the route command does is look it up and translate it to an ip address. So if pandora.com presently resolves to 172.16.0.1, then what the machine is really doing is adding a route to 172.16.0.1/32 via ppp0. When the machine decides how to route a packet, it does so using the ip addresses and masks you set up, whatever domain name you used is long forgotten at that stage.

In order to add routes for all machines in the domain, you would have to know all the ip addresses, which means you need to know all the host names already. If your DNS server is set up to allow that sort of thing, you could ask it for everything in the pandora.com domain, but very few dns servers will allow that sort of thing nowadays.

But... if you know that everything in pandora.com has an ip address starting between, for example, 172.16.0.0 and 172.16.0.255 (the so called net block, the kind of thing you can get using whois) you could add a route for the whole network, eg:

```
ip route add 172.16.0.0/24 dev ppp0
```

Note also that I used the iproute2 command there rather than /sbin/route.